Use keymap-global-set to define Option+Shift+<up>
I'm running emacs from an iTerm2 command line. I currently have the following two lines in .emacs:
(keymap-global-set   "ESC <up>"      'scroll-down-command)
(keymap-global-set   "ESC <down>"    'scroll-up-command)

On my Mac, this is done with Option+ArrowKey. I'd like to add key bindings to scroll-other-window- variants of the above, using for instance Option+Shift+ArrowKey or Option+Control+ArrowKey. I haven't found a way of doing this. Is there any way to modify a Mac arrow key with something besides Option?
;; (keymap-global-set   "ESC <up>"      'scroll-other-window-down)
;; (keymap-global-set   "ESC <down>"    'scroll-other-window-up)


This question is similar to: Shift+Up isn't recognized by Emacs in a terminal. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You’re using Emacs inside of a terminal, so it is subject to the limitations of the terminal. Seek out all the past answers where I and others have explained these limitations in great detail, and the possible ways around them. Short answer: you can’t.

Specifically in the case of iterm2, you can do this, by going to Settings/profiles, selecting a profile, then in "Keys/General", ensure that "Treat ⌥ as Alt" is enabled, as well as "Left Option key: Esc+"
